# Accumulation points and infinitely many points inside open balls

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $(X, \Vert \cdot\Vert)$ be a normed space and $A \subset X$.
If $x \in X$ is an accumulation point of $A$, does every open ball $B(x, r)$,
where $r > 0$ contain infinitely many points of $A$?

#### A Contraposition

Suppose there exists an open ball $B(x, r)$, that only contains a few or no points of $A$. In the case of no points, the point $x$ is by definition *not* an accumulation point of $A$, contradicting the initial assumption.

Now the question is, how do I handle the case of some points in $A$? I know that $X$ is a normed space, meaning I might be able to use the norm axioms to somehow contradict either the initial assumption that $A \subset X$, or the limit point status of $x$, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: suppose there are only finitely many points $\{x_i\}_{i < N}$ for some $N \in {\mathbb N}$.  Then $\|x_i-x_j\| = \epsilon_j > 0$ for each fixed $i$ and all $j$.  So you can construct an open ball around each of the those points of suitable radius to exclude all other points.

Comment: @postmortes So our justification for the open balls $B(x_i,\varepsilon)$ not containing any other points in $A$ is that the radius $\varepsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small, specifically $\varepsilon < \varepsilon_j$?

Comment: @postmortes And the reason we care about distinctness is that if we can't guarantee distinctness for each of the points $x_i$, there is no way for there to be an infinite number of points for certain, as some of them might be the same? Also, in your notation, is $j = N$?

Comment: If points aren't distinct they're the same point.  You need finitely many points for this argument; with infinitely many points you would need an extra condition to prevent the $\epsilon_j$ from approaching 0 and allowing the points to cluster/accumulate.  And $1\leq j \leq N$ is the relation you're missing.

Comment: Ok. And just to clarify, we are still trying to topple $x$ from being an accumulation point? The fact that all of the $N - 1$ points in $A \cap B(x, r) \neq \emptyset$ are distinct shows that how, exactly? There is an answer already, but I'm trying to understand this approach as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can construct a sequence $x_n \to x$ from which the result follows.

Choose $x_1 \in B(x,1)\setminus \{x\}$.

Now suppose we have constructed $x_1,...,x_n$, then choose $x_{n+1} \in B\big(x, \min( \|x-x_n\|, {1 \over n})\big) \setminus \{x\}$.

Since $\|x_{n+1}-x\| < \|x_n-x\|$ we see that all the points are distinct and
since $\|x_n-x\| < {1 \over n}$ we see that $x_n \to x$.

Comment: So $x$ is still an accumulation point of $A$, so we can take the radius of $1$ for the punctured ball $B_1'(x,1)$ to represent a certain point $x_1$. Another punctured ball, $B_2'(x,\min(\Vert x - x_1 \Vert), 1/1))$ is then constructed to contain at least the point $x_2$, $B_3'(x,\min(\Vert x - x_2 \Vert), 1/2))$ to represent the point $x_3$ and so forth.

Comment: It's just that I don't see immediately, how $\Vert x_{n+1} - x\Vert < \Vert x_n - x\Vert$, or that $\Vert x_n - x\Vert < 1/n$. Also, how does the distinctness of the points lead us to a contradiction?

Comment: Is the sequence characterization of accumulation points used here?

Comment: If $y \in B(x,r)$ then $\|x-y\| < r$. Well, you need distinct points in order to conclude that any ball contains an infinite number of points. I am not sure what a 'sequence characterization of accumulation points' means.

Comment: According to the lecture notes I'm reading, you can define accumulation points using either open balls or sequences, and then prove the representations are equivalent. And your approach looks very much like the sequence definition: $x_0 \in M$ is an accumulation point of $A \subset M$, iff there exists a sequence $(x_n) \subset A, x \neq x_n$, so that $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I guess I'm struggling with even the basic idea of why you would want to construct a sequence in the first place, as we already know such a thing exists as $x$ is an accumulation point of $A$. From my point of view you simply showed, that a distinct (I guess this is the relevant part) sequence of points converges towards the accumulation point of $A$. Why does distinctness imply the sequence is infinite in each open ball $B(x,r)$?

Comment: I think I got it now, as a friend came by to clarify things for me. As $x$ is an accumulation point, we can choose punctured balls of infinitely smaller and smaller radii in order to show that there indeed is an infinite number of points around the accumulation point. I was stuck in contraposition mode. I'm just not sure why you would need to think about the minimum of $\{ \Vert x - x_n \Vert, 1/n \}$: Wouldn't $1/n$ suffice as a radius?

Comment: @SeSodesa: Well, using ${ 1\over n}$ will work as well, but you need to show that $\{x_n\}$ is infinite so it adds another line to the proof. By expliciitly constructing a distinct collection of points it follows immediately that there are an infinite number.